# How do I hide xml file?

Tags: asp.net, xml, seo, file-security

How do I hide xml file? I don't want to appear the file in google results. How I access denied this file for user?

Comment: Find out about [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/). Using a `robots.txt` you can tell robots not to index/crawl certain areas of your website.

Comment: there isnt xml file url in robots.txt file

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to appear the file in google results.

Create a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file to instruct search engines not to index it.

> How I access denied this file for user?

Add in some layer of authentication+authorisation. Preferably the same one as the rest of your site uses.